# Kotlin String Operation

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to create a logic such that

```
if I Input "1-2+4" in Android TextView and after clicking a button
the output should Display as follows
1 - 2 = -1 // 1st line
-1 + 4 = 3 // 2nd line and so on...
 
without BODMAS Rule like, 
first addition then minus etc., it should follow my input sequence
```

I tried a lot of String Functions, but cant find the exact logic...By using string functions, I am getting type mismatch etc., such kind of errors....
I request anyone to held and guide me..
Thank You

Comment: What are the operations that you want to support other than plus and minus? Do you allow brackets as well? And can the input string have spaces and other invalid characters?

Comment: Can you show what you tried? It's a lot easier to correct what's wrong with your code than to explain how to do it completely from scratch and possibly reviewing things you already know for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick iteration on what you are looking for. Regex is powerful yet dangerous, and when they get modified past their original usage, things start to fall apart.

Key points here.

1. We do everything with integers inside of the `operateBy` method, this helps Kotlin know that we are working with Integers only, otherwise it has a hard time knowing which types we are expecting due to the many different types that exist for Int::minus
2. The key magic is in the `Integer.parseInt` method, this takes our strings and makes them numbers, so we can actually do math with them, otherwise casting from string to Int can lead to unexpected results
3. We use the nullability of `cmd?.destructured?.run` to imply that we had a successful and complete match. Otherwise we realize we have hit the end of the input

---

```
val input = "1-2+4+8-4/7*3"

val regex = Regex("""(-?\d+)([-+/*])(-?\d+)(.*)""")

parseInput(input)
println("Done!")

fun Int.operateBy(symbol: String, other: Int): Int = when(symbol) {
    "-" -> minus(other)
    "+" -> plus(other)
    "/" -> div(other)
    "*" -> times(other)
    else -> other
}

fun parseInput(commands: String) {
    if (commands.isEmpty()) return
    val cmd = regex.find(commands)
    
    cmd?.destructured?.run {
        val first = component1()
        val second = component2()
        val third = component3()
        val fourth = component4()

        try {
            val a = Integer.parseInt(first)
            val b = Integer.parseInt(third)
            val result = a.operateBy(second, b)

            println("$a $second $b = $result")
            parseInput("$result$fourth")
        } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
            println("Error messaging")
        }
    }
}
```

---

This prints the output:

```
1 - 2 = -1
-1 + 4 = 3
3 + 8 = 11
11 - 4 = 7
7 / 7 = 1
1 * 3 = 3
Done!
```